# How do I calculate Date Difference between row observations in R

Tags: sql, r, datediff

Here is the sample dataframe (Market_Test) [Not sure of DataFrame comes out properly or not hence the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxQGe.png)

```
Submarket   Market          Date            URL of test
Seattle_Sub1    Seattle         1/2/2016        Abc.com/test1
Seattle_Sub2    Seattle         1/3/2016        Abc.com/test2
Seattle_Sub1    Seattle         1/5/2016        Abc.com/test3
Portland_Sub1   Portland    1/15/2016   Abc.com/test4
Portland_Sub2   Portland    1/10/2016   Abc.com/test3
Portland_Sub2   Portland    1/11/2016   Abc.com/test2
Portland_Sub1   Portland    1/10/2016   Abc.com/test1
```

I need to calculate and pivot the data on the SubMarket Level and make it look like the following [OutputData Frame Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH6uv.png)-

```
Submarket   Market       No of Days Testing   Gap b/w test Days
Seattle_Sub1    Seattle           2                3
Seattle_Sub2    Seattle           1                0
Portland_Sub1   Portland      2                5
Portland_Sub2   Portland      2                1
```

There are around 300,000 observations so relatively big data set.

I am able to easily solve the No of Days Testing problem using sqldf and distinct count but hit a roadblock with Gap b/w Test Days calculation.

One thing I tried was using rank the original datframe and then calcualte the delta between 2 values of rank but in ddply but that takes very long, infact it never gets completed.

```
Inputdf <- mutate(Inputdf,Date_Rank = rank(Date))
```

Otheroption would have been to use lag/lead functions in sql but sqldf does not allow that.

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: Please provide problem and your best attempt in minimal reproducible form, i.e. so that anyone else can *easily* copy it from your post & paste it into their session & see the results.  All library statements & inputs must be provided.  Post output of `dput(whatever)` to show input data reproducibly.  For more info on how to pose a question see (1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example (2)  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (3) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask